# Drop down list from database php/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to create a dropdown list from database with javascript.
I am trying to make a dynamic form where I can add multiple rows using "add more" button.
My html form contains an input type text and a drop down list

in html

```
<form id="add_name" name="add_name">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
<tr>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="nom_ar">
    <?php                   
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value='".$row2['nom_ar']."'>".$row2['nom_ar']."   </option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="insert name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">add more</button></td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>
```

In the javascript code I added only the input type text and I don't know how to add the dropdown list like the next code shows :

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select class="form-control" name="nom_ar"><?php while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){echo "<option value='".$row2['nom_ar']."'>".$row2['nom_ar']."</option>";} ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Ingredient" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
```

}

How can I do it? My drop down list in js is always empty. I'm struggling as I'm a beginner. where should I put the php code?

Comment: To start with, your table is invalid. You're missing `<td></td>` around the select-box.

Comment: I think you're trying to attack too advanced of a concept without understanding some fundamentals. Firstly, does your drop down menu successfully populate from the DB? If so, maybe try add more rows using PHP, before you try JS.

This `$('#add')` syntax is jQuery, have you included the jquery src in your code? 
https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is your JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add').click(function() {
            $("#dynamic_field").append("<tr></tr>");
            $.post("server.php", {
                        object_field:   "Any data", 
                    }, function(server_data) {
                        $("#dynamic_field tr:last-child").html(parse_server_data(server_data));
                    });
                });

    function parse_server_data(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var output_string = "<td><select>";
            for (var key in data) {
                var value = data[key];
                output_string += "<option value=" + key + ">" + value + "</option>";
            }
            output_string += "</select></td>";

            return output_string;
    }
</script>
```

1. I intentionally segregated server-side code (server.php file) and js code. Why? You should not mix code from server-side and client-side, use power of ajax technologies. 
   Add to server.php your code that echo's all necessary data (in your case - your fetch_assoc). Learn about MVC model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
2. I also added JSON.parse function. JSON is standard of data compression and submission, check json_encode/json_decode functions in PHP and use them
3. Don't use tables a lot, practice divs/spans